# Issues with the edited form

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue with submission of the edited form. When I'm trying to click the submit button, the form isn't closing. Here is the code

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      initial: true,
    };

    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        const { change, calendarEvent } = this.props;
        if (newProps.calendarEvent !== calendarEvent) {
          if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.calendarEvent.summary) {
            change('title', newProps.calendarEvent.summary);
          }

          if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.calendarEvent.description) {
            change('description', newProps.calendarEvent.description);
          }

          if (newProps.calendarEvent && newProps.calendarEvent.start.dateTime) {
            const hours = moment(newProps.calendarEvent.start.dateTime).format('hh');
            change('hour', parseInt(hours));
            const minutes = moment(newProps.calendarEvent.start.dateTime).format('mm');
            change('minute', parseInt(minutes));
            const period = moment(newProps.calendarEvent.start.dateTime).format('A');
            change('period', period);
          }
        }
      }

      handleCloseModal() {
        this.props.resetForm();
        this.props.onHide(false);
      }

      handleFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { formError, formValues, onSubmit, calendarEvent, touchFields } = this.props;

        if (!formValues.title || !formValues.period || !formValues.hour || !formValues.minute) {
          touchFields();
        } else if (!formError) {
          onSubmit({ event: calendarEvent, formValues });
        }
      }
```

Somehow, the method handleFormSubmit isn't working. What is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

After onSumbit call try to call this.handleCloseModal();

Comment: Tried, no changes. handleCloseModal is working when you click on X in the modal.

Comment: @СерегаБубело are you trying to bind that call or make this function as a arrow function?

Comment: I added the code in the question so you can see. I'm binding. I have a calendar so I can add and edit events. The edit form works properly only on one date. All the other dates - it works incorrectly, it's not closing after clicking the submit button

Comment: try to call handleCloseModal inside handleFormSubmit method. Will it works?

Comment: @СерегаБубело What it was?

Comment: const minutes = moment(newProps.calendarEvent.start.dateTime).format('m');
change('minute', minutes);

correct version/